# Unnable to list snapshots in Elasticsearch repository

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, devops

I have an Elasticsearch snapshot repository configured to folder on NFS share, and i'm unable to do list snapshots because of strange errors

```
curl -X GET "10.0.1.159:9200/_cat/snapshots/temp_elastic_backup?v&s=id&pretty"

{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parse_exception",
        "reason" : "start object expected"   
      }
    ]
    "type" : "parse_exception",
    "reason" : "start object expected"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Which version are you using?

Comment: i'm using 7.4.1 version